# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los valores de un arreglo con un "FOREACH"?

Tags: php

```
$num_naturals = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
                  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
                  61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
                  81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
                );

echo("<br>");
```

> Ciclo con el cual debo hacer
> la sumatoria de todos los números
> del arreglo:

```
foreach($num_naturals as $clave => $valor)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> En realidad no necesitas de un ciclo, no al menos de forma explícita.

- Es decir PHP nos provee de [`array_sum()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php) método que recibe como argumento un array de valores
- Este método realiza de forma interna un ciclo que iterará todos los elementos
- Al final nos entregará un único valor numérico que será el resultado

Con lo anterior puedes sacar de la jugada al ciclo `foreach` que nos estás mostrando en tu pregunta.

```
$num_naturals = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
                  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
                  61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
                  81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
                );
                
$resultado = array_sum($num_naturals);

echo $resultado;
```

> 5050

Answer (score 0):

Usa `array_reduce`:

```
function suma($var, $item){
   $var += $item;
   return $var;
}

$num_naturals = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
                  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
                  61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
                  81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
                );

$resultado = array_reduce($num_naturals, "suma");
echo $resultado;
```

Esta es la documentacion de `array_reduce`:

[array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php)

Lo que hace `array_reduce`, es que toma un arreglo y lo reduce a un valor dependiendo de un `callback` que le pasemos, en este caso le pasamos la funcion `suma`, en este caso al tratarse de numeros y la forma en la que esta construida la funcion `suma`, lo que pasara es que el resultado almacenado por la variable `$resultado` será la sumatoria de todos los numeros que pusiste.

Por lo tanto ya no necesitaremos usar un ciclo `for` para hacer la suma de todos esos valores y guardar el resultado en una variable.

Si solo deseas hacerlo mediante un `foreach` puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
$num_naturals = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
                  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
                  61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
                  81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
                );

//Declaramos una variable que almacenara el resultado de tu suma.
$resultado = 0;

foreach($num_naturals as $value){
   $resultado += $value;
}

echo $resultado;
```

Aclaremos unas cuantas cosas aqui:

`foreach` tiene dos formas de ejecutarse, la primera (y usada anteriormente) es para arreglos indexados (arreglos normales de toda la vida), la segunda se usa para arreglos asociativos, donde el primer parametro o valor debera ser el **arreglo a recorrer**, y el segundo será una variable que se crea en el mismo ciclo, la cual contendra el valor del arreglo en esa iteracion, (en nuestro caso se trata de `$val`):

```
foreach($arr as $val){
   ...
}
```

Esto es para los arreglos indexados (con indices numericos), para los **arreglos asociativos** se usa una manera distinta del ciclo, la cual es esta:

```
$asociativeArr = ["nombre" => "juan", "edad" => 18];

foreach($asociativeArr as $key => $value){
    echo $key ": " . $value . "<br>";
}
```

Donde `$asociativeArr` se traduce al arreglo que deseamos recorrer con `foreach`, `$key` se crea en el ciclo y contiene la llave asociativa actual con la que se accede a los valores del array, un ejemplo de llaves seria (`nombre` y `edad`), `$value` representa el valor que contiene ese arreglo asociativo en esa determinada `$key` (pocision).

Por lo que tu confusion se debe a que estabas usando la forma de recorrer arreglos asociativos con un `foreach` en algo que **NO** es un `array asociativo`.

Answer (score 0):

resolviendo tu duda, es de la siguiente forma:

```
$suma;
$num_naturals = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
                  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
                  61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
                  81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100);

foreach($num_naturals as $clave){
  $suma = (sizeof($num_naturals) + 1 ) / 2 * $clave;
}

echo $suma;
#5050
```

Es un poco de matemática conocida como propiedad conmutativa de la suma, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Agrego una cosa a las buenas soluciones anteriores:

Si necesitás sumar números naturales consecutivos (como en el ejemplo), no necesitás recorrer el array. Basta con obtener el último valor del array, y usar esta fórmula:

N(N+1)/2

En tu caso, sería:

```
$num_naturals = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
                  21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
                  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60,
                  61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80,
                  81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100
                );

$maxValue = end($num_naturals);
$suma = ($maxValue * $maxValue+1)/2;
```

Ahí no tenés necesidad ni de tener los valores en el array, ni de recorrerlo. Obviamente, funciona como una sumatoria.

Si querés calcular la sumatoria de 1 a 100, basta con pasarle el valor, sin necesidad de tener el array y (aún mejor) de recorrerlo:

```
$maxValue = 100;
$suma = ($maxValue * ($maxValue+1))/2;
```

No creo que sea el caso tuyo, pero a alguien quizás le puede servir.
Se basa en este concepto:
Imaginate que quiero saber cual es la sumatoria desde el numero 1 al 10. Tranquilamente yo podría organizar esos valores así:

```
1   2  3  4  5
10  9  8  7  6
```

Luego, si hago la suma de cada columna, me queda:

```
1   2  3  4  5
10  9  8  7  6
--------------
11 11 11 11 11
```

En tanto, es lo mismo sumar 1 + 2 + 3 + 4... etc que sumar 5 veces 11. Genéricamente, es lo mismo sumar 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N que sumar N/2 veces N+1.

```
N/2 * (N+1) --> Agrupando, queda N(N+1)/2.
```

Saludos!